# What does requestCode represent?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-pendingintent

I thought requestCode was some kind of indentifier for which Intent was just called for or something like that, please correct me if i'm wrong. But if this is the case, why is that if the requestCode for my pendingintent is 2, it acts differently when I have pass the requestcode as 0. I don't have another pendingintent in which is passed 2 as the requestcode.

Say I start my app and then I get a notification, when I click this notification ...

**requestCode = 2**
...a new activity is created and brought to the foreground, when I press the back button I go back to the activity I was on in the same state before backing out of the app

**requestCode = 0**
...I go straight back to the activity I was on in the same state before backing out of the app. No new activity is created

This isn't really a big issue, I could just pass 0 and the app will work how I want it to but I just wanna know why this happens.

**In MainActivity.kt**

```
    private fun startAlarm (cal : Calendar){
        val alarmManager :AlarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent (this, AlertReceiver().javaClass)
        val pendingIntent : PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0)
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
    }
}
```

**AlertReceiver.kt**

```
class AlertReceiver(): BroadcastReceiver() {

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val notificationObj : Notification = Notification(context)
        val notif : NotificationCompat.Builder = notificationObj.createNotification()

        notificationObj.getManager().notify(1, notif.build())
    }
}
```

**In Notification.kt**

```
fun createNotification(): NotificationCompat.Builder{
        val main: Intent = Intent (this, MainActivity().javaClass).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        //-------------------talking about this line--------------------------------
        val pendingMain: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2, main, 0)
        val notif : NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, channelID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("test:")
            .setContentText("testing")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingMain)
            .setAutoCancel((true))

        return notif
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully followed your question, but requestCode should have no effect on _how_ your activity starts. It's just an ID you can check in the Activity for whatever purpose you want. Maybe you were changing the intent flags?

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, I didn't think it the requestCode would really effect it either. But it seems when I change the requestcode from anything that isn't 0, it creates a new new copy of the activity on top of the original one whenever I click the notification. I've tested so many times, touching nothing in the code except the requestcode. Kind of odd

Comment: You are using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` so I would expect a new Activity regardless of the requestCode.

Comment: Are you creating any `PendingIntent` with `MainActivity` as the target anywhere else in your code? Because your explanation makes no sense at all. Since you have used the flags `NEW_TASK` and `CLEAR_TASK` the behaviour should be neither of the 2 scenarios you described. Also, please edit your question and paste the relevant `<activity>` declaration from the manifest in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing data from multiple Fragments to an Activity using onActivityResult(), that Activity identifies the child Fragment via request code